# How to install dotnetfx35.exe

Tags: windows-server-2016, installation

OS: W2K16

Hi All,

I need to install "dotnetfx35.exe" in my W2K16 server but when I lauch the install he say me:

```
The following feature couldn't be install:
.Net Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)

Windows Server roles and features cannot be automatically or uninstalled via the Windows Features Control Panel.

To install Windows Server roles and features, start Server Manager, or use the Server Manager cmdlets for Windows PowerShell.
```

You can see my windowsshoot:

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf1ZK.png)

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, you need:

1. Mount ISO File <<-- MANDATORY
2. Server Manager
3. Add Roles and Features, new window is open
4. Click in Features
5. Select .Net Framework 3.5
6. Install

Cordially!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Server Manager, the add Roles and Features, then select the .NET Framework you need under the Framework tab. (You may need to click next until you get to the features tab)